# Page not found unit tests using Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, unit-testing, spring-mvc

**Page not found unit tests using Spring**

How fix this error in my case?

All worked, there were no changhes as I remember.

Here is a [github link to the project.](https://github.com/arthurdn/abc.git)

But now... 404 code.

Test

```
class WebIntegrityTest extends BaseWebSpecification {
private List controllers = []
//setup
controllers << new PaymentController()   

def "Charge"() {
    when:
    ResultActions result = performGet("/perform", controllers)

    then:
    result.andExpect(isOk)
}
}
```

Base

```
abstract class BaseWebSpecification extends BaseSpecification {
protected static final ResultMatcher isOk//...

protected static ResultActions performGet(String url, Object... controllers) {
    buildMockMvc(controllers).perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(url))
}

private static MockMvc buildMockMvc(Object... controllers) {
    MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controllers).build()
}
}
```

Spring

```
4.3.2.RELEASE
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/web-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller

```
package com.abc.payments.controllers;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/perform")
public class PaymentController {
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public String perform() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    return "{\"test\":\"test\"}";
}
}
```

Context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.payments.controllers"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: dropbox link is not working. Can you share the github link for the project?

Comment: https://github.com/arthurdn/abc.git